# Does the command `reboot` hurt a Mac computer?

Tags: macos, mac, mojave, shutdown, reboot

Does the command `reboot` (used in Terminal) hurt the computer?  Because it is almost like pulling the power cord, which is not a recommended way to power down a computer.

Comment: Super clear. I appreciate you making this brief and objective.

Comment: Just an **FYI**: If you click the **Apple** menu and then **Restart…** the `/sbin/reboot` _command_ is actually called by **macOS**  as part of the _reboot process_.

Comment: but just typing `reboot` in the terminal doesn't seem to include the steps that gracefully shut down the apps

Comment: It only hurts the user ;-).

Answer (score 32):

It’s not like pulling the power plug because it sends various signals like `SIGTERM` which closes services and daemons.  User applications with unsaved data may get lost, but they’re not arbitrarily closed as if the system lost power.

From the man page ([`man reboot`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/8/reboot/))

> The halt and reboot utilities flush the file system cache to disk, send all running processes a SIGTERM (and subsequently a SIGKILL) and,
>        respectively, halt or restart the system.

So, running `reboot` is perfectly safe to the system.

Comment: This is not the same as the shutdown command which will stop services in order

Comment: typing `reboot` in the terminal doesn't seem to include the steps that gracefully shut down the apps

Comment: @nonopolarity correct but that is another question

Comment: @DarkHeart Looking at shutdown's code https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-854.40.2/shutdown.tproj/shutdown.c.auto.html I think shutdown just calls reboot and so behaves the same unless -o is passed where launchd does the process

Comment: @user151019 - I think you have that the wrong way around. My point it that you’d want launchd to do its thing instead of just indiscriminately killing all processes.

Comment: @DarkHeart Yes sorry you are correct (I misread a !)

Comment: @user151019 actually, if the app is killed in the middle, I'd consider it somewhat hurting the computer. What if I highlighted a few lines in a PDF ebook file using Preview, and (1) Preview has not written it to the hard drive?  (2) What if it had written half of it to the hard drive but half is not written?  Maybe the journaled file system will "save the day" for (2) because the file won't be corrupted as the file system will consider nothing is written at all? But for (1) or (2) there is lost of work (the highlightings)

Comment: Reboot flushes to disk, so you may lose unsaved changes, but it's impossible to get filesystem corruption.

Comment:  Strange stuff in this old source code... `void die_you_gravy_sucking_pig_dog(void);`

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that (to my knowledge) most Cocoa apps don't handle SIGTERM the same way they do a Quit command, so it's possible some state/data would be lost if an application was holding it in memory. (However, autosaving has become quite common, and apps have been encouraged to support [Automatic Termination and Sudden Termination](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW27) for a long time.)

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/die-you-gravy-sucking-pig-dog/